# When creating a new project in Visual studio 2013 I get an error because they are automatically trying to use IIS express

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

When creating a new Web API ASP.NET project I get the error "Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error: Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.

The problem with this error is that I don't even have IIS express installed any more so I want to associate new projects with regular IIS. I can manually change the settings of the project by opening it in notepad. But this is pretty annoying and I can't see where to change the default.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating web project in VS, IIS Express is assumed to be on the machine (because VS puts it there).  If you've removed that required dependency, your machine is in an unsupported state.  Why not just have IIS Express installed, and change the projects after creating them?